# Set Password on Test User Account in Localhost

Tags: users, user-profile, password, craft2

I'm trying to set the password for a 'test' user account on my localhost test site.  I don't have an email server to send the reset emails, so I've been using the copy URL method.
When I do go to the URL and change the password, I get a 'Page Not Found' page.  I went ahead and checked to see if the password was in fact changed, but upon successive login tests, they failed.
I was wondering what might be causing the 'Page Not Found' error?  Is there a way to set the password through a plugin, etc?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a Craft-styled 404 Page Not Found or a web-server styled one?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the database you can change the user's password to: `$2y$13$FfVKvo1W1N5Gsba3c19r8uz.x9R5NRQgRu8jmXvOjVCStg1sKGcoW` which is 'secret' when un-hashed.

Source: https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/1063135843441954816

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can not comment yet.

Do you try copy your admin password to your test user in database? It can be way. Do you debug the "Page Not Found" error?